# IOS Universal Link works and redirects from website to app but leaves a 404 (safari) sendinblue email error behind. Why?

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Im wondering is this is normal: I have  set up universal links which work - after clicking on link I see my website for like a second and then im being redirected to my app. When I open safari afterwards, I should see my website, but I see a 404 page/im sending the link via email using 'sendinBlue' and the 404 page shows a sendinblue email error.
I couldnt find anything online and dont think providing code is relevant as the linking to my app works.

Does someone know why this is happening?

Comment: It sounds like 'sendInBlue' is modifying the embedded url so that it first goes to their site and then they are performing a redirect to your url. This is typically done for reasons like analytics. Is there an option to tell sendInBlue to not rewrite the link?